# Envió de parámetros a una cadena JSON para el consumo de una API, C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, api, email

una duda que tengo es si hay una forma de enviar unos valores o parámetros asignados por el usuario para el envió de un correo, actualmente estoy tratando de implementar una `API` de creación de **tickets**, explico a detalle.
En mi aplicación tengo el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
    var mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.Subject = string.Format("{0} - {1}", config.Subject,info.ClaimCode);
    mail.Body = String.Format("{0}\n\nGracias,\n{1}", info.MessageToSend, 
    config.UserName); ;
    mail.From = new MailAddress(config.UserMail, string.IsNullOrEmpty(config.UserName) ? "Maxi" : 
    config.UserName);
    mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

    if (config.BCCMail != "")
    {
        mail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(config.BCCMail));
    }

    mail.ReplyToList.Add(config.UserMail);
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(config.UserMail));
```

El anterior código muestra las partes que conforman un email (`subject, body, from, etc.`) esos datos o valores son ingresados por el usuario.

Y en el código de mi `API` tengo una cadena `JSON` que es la siguiente:

> string json = "{\"priority\": 1,
>   \"email\":\"email@email.com\",\"subject\":\"OUTBOUND
>   TEST\",\"description\":\"Outbound email test
>   succesfully\",\"cc_emails\":[\"email1@email.com\",\"email2@email.com\"]}";

lo que quiero saber si hay una forma de enviar los datos que ingresa el usuario (`mail.subject`, `mail.Body`, `etc`) a esa cadena `json` para el consumo de la `API`, no se si se pueda crear un `jsonObject` y después usar un `JavaScriptSerializer()`

Tengo un metodo que se llamar 'NotificationGatewayInfo' en donde tengo el siguiente codigo en donde declaro mis variables a utilizar para el envio del correo:

```html
public class NotificationGatewayInfo
    {
        #region Info 

        public IEnumerable<DocumentDto> Documents { get; set; }
        public string BeneficiaryPhone { get; set; }
        public int IdentificationType { get; set; }
        public string MessageToSend { get; set; }
        public string CustomerPhone { get; set; }
        public bool IsInfoRequired { get; set; }
        public bool SendBsaFormat { get; set; }
        public bool SendBtsFormat { get; set; }
        public bool SendTnFormat { get; set; }
        public string Ssn { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string PaymentType { get; set; }
        public string BeneficiaryName { get; set; }
        public string DestinationCountry { get; set; }
        public object PayerName { get; set; }
    }
```

y mi método public donde envió y evaluó mi email es el siguiente:

```html
public OperationResponse SendNotificationGateway(UserSession userSession, NotificationGatewayInfo info)
```

si necesitan mas explicación para poder ayudarme mejor, estoy al pendiente
Gracias!!

Comment: No te sirve armar todas las variables en el front? Ignoro si utilizas angular | ajax o algo similar

Comment: Muéstrame como enviaría los datos el usuario , como estas manejando las `api` puedes verlas desde `Swagger` ? como recibe el método los datos y como tienes declarado el método ?, Ese **JSON** que muestras como lo construyes o de donde llega ?

Comment: edite mi publicación donde proporciono los GET and SET en mi método  'NotificationGatewayInfo' y como tengo declarado el método

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un json puede mapear a clases de .net por lo tanto si defines

```
public class MailData{
   public int priority {get;set;}
   public string email {get;set;}
   public string subject {get;set;}
   public string description {get;set;}
   public List<string> cc_emails {get;set;}
}
```

Puedes luego serializar la instancia de esa clase usando [json.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

entonces quedaria

```
 MailData mailData = new MailData();
 mailData.priority = 1;
 mailData.subject = mail.Subject;
 mailData.cc_emails = new List<string>() { "email1@email.com", "email2@email.com" };
 //resto propiedades

 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mailData);
```

es mas simple trabjar con instancias de clase y serializar que unir los valores en un string

Comment: Perfecto, entonces en mi API en lugar de usar esa cadena JSON que muestro, puedo serializar a la clase donde tengo todos mis GET and SET, y así lograría que los datos que ingresa el usuario, mi API los pueda consumir sin problema?

Comment: claro esa es la idea

Answer (score 0):

Mira este ejemplo puede que te sirva:

Lo primero sera construir un `Dto` o una clase de la siguiente forma:

```
 public class DtoEmail
    {
        private int Priority;
        private string Email;
        private string SubJect;
        private string Description;
        private List<string> CC_Emails;
        private string Body;
        private string UserName;
        private string UserMail;
    }
```

En el controlador donde esta el método `API` debes tener algo similar a esto:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("NombreTuMetodo")]
 public HttpResponseMessage NombreTuMetodo(DtoEmail datosEnviadosUsuario)
 {
   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, this.TuMetodo(datosEnviadosUsuario));
 }
```

Ahora en el método donde tienes el fragmento de código:

Deberías de hacer es acceder a las propiedades que se envían en el `Dto`

```
 public tipoRetorno TuMetodo(DtoEmail emailDto)
 {
  var mail = new MailMessage();

  mail.Subject = emailDto.SubJect;
  mail.Body = emailDto.Body; ;
  mail.From = new MailAddress(emailDto.Email, string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailDto.UsarName));
  mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

  if (emailDto.CC_Emails.length >= 0)
  {
     foreach (var itemCCEmails in emailDto.CC_Emails)
     {
        mail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(itemCCEmails));
     }
  }

  mail.ReplyToList.Add(emailDto.UserMail);
  mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailDto.UserMail));
}
```

Si necesitas que le método retorne algo solo cambia `tipoRetorno` por lo que necesites algún tipo de dato o una lista.

Comment: Perfecto, lo del HttpPost es el código que iría en mi código de mi API?

Comment: Si , exacto, puedes definir mas propiedades en tu clase, debes cambiar `tipoRetorno`por `OperationResponse` y retornar lo que necesitas.

Comment: entendido, me parece buen ejemplo, agradezco mucho tu ayuda